# Is the cube root of a prime number rational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, radicals, rationality-testing

The question is: if $P$ is prime, is $P^{1/3}$ rational?

I have been able to prove that if $P$ is prime then the square root of $P$ isn't rational (by contradiction) how would I go about the cube root?

Comment: If $P$ is prime then neither $\sqrt{P}$ or $\sqrt[3]{P}$ is an integer, so the notion of primality makes no sense for them (tiny caveat: over $\mathbb{Z}$) and the simplest sensible answer is 'no'.

Comment: How can I rigorously prove that?

Comment: If $\sqrt{P} = a$ is a prime integer, then $P = a\cdot a$ is a prime factorization of $P$...

Comment: Omid: try searching for 'irrationality of square root proof' in your favorite search engine; there are several standard proofs, starting from various different sets of core principles, and you're sure to find one to your tastes somewhere in the stack.

Comment: Check your claimed proof that if P is prime then √P is prime: surely there is some error in it, because if n=√P is an integer, then P=n^2 is not prime.

Comment: my apologies, I meant to type rational not prime. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Of course not, for reasons quite similar to those already explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality).

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $\sqrt[3]{P} = \dfrac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ have no common factors (i.e. the fraction is in reduced form). Then you have

$$
b^3 P = a^3.
$$

Both sides must be divisible by $a$ (if they're both equal to $a^3$). We already know that $a$ does not divide $b$ (when we assumed the fraction is reduced). So then $a$ must divide $P$.

EDIT: and if $a = 1$, then $P = \dfrac{1}{b^3}$. How many integers are of the form $\dfrac{1}{B}$ for some $B$?

Comment: To be pedantic, you need to add a line saying why $a = 1$ isn't possible either. :-)

Comment: That would be *very* pedantic.  P is prime, therefore greater than 1, therefore its roots are greater than 1, therefore a > b, but b is an integer greater than 0, therefore 0 < b < 1.  No integers exist (as far as I know) between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

The main point is: The cube root of a natural number is rational iff it is infact an integer. More generally, any rational root of a monic  polynomial with integer coefficients (such as $X^3-n$) is in fact integer. So if $\sqrt[3] n$ is rational then $n$ is a cube (and cannot be prime).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $ $ Any rational root of $\,x^3-p\,$  is an integer, by the  [Rational Root Test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Alternatively $\, a^3 = pb^3\,$ contradicts the *uniqueness of prime factorizations*, since the prime $\,p\,$ occurs to power a multiple of $\,3\,$ on the lhs, but a nonmultiple $\,1\!+\!3n\,$ on  rhs, i.e. $\,0\not\equiv 1\pmod 3.\,$  This is a generalization of the analogous proof of irrationality of square-roots by comparing the *parity* of exponents of $\,p,\,$ i.e. $\,0\not\equiv 1\pmod 2,\,$ i.e. even $\ne $ odd. Precisely the same proof works for $k$'th roots, by employing that $\ 0\not\equiv 1\pmod{\! k}$