# Prove that for $x^3=3$ there isn't rational solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that for $x^3=3$ there isn't rational solution

**What I did:**

Suppose $x= u /v$ is solution

$$\left(\frac u v\right)^3=3$$

Let's take third root from both sides:

$$\frac u v =\sqrt[3]3$$

and $\sqrt[3]3$ is irrationl ,

my problem is this "and $\sqrt[3]3$ is irrationl " is it well known that this number is irrationl? same as $\pi$?

or maybe there is another why to prove it?

Comment: [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: The classic proof of irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ can be adapted to $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

Comment: My guess is that the point of the exercise is to prove that $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is irrational, so using that is probably not acceptable.

Comment: @Henrik Yes, you are right

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675327/is-the-cube-root-of-a-prime-number-rational?

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion tells you $x^{3}-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since it is a cubic, this implies there are no zeroes in $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, there is no rational number that satisfies the equation.

Comment: $x^3 = 3$ and $x = \sqrt[3]3$ are pretty much a synonymous definition [not exactly as there are theoretically 3 possible such numbers but... that's another story] so, no, this is not a solution.  This is equivalent to proving $7^9 - 8$ is odd by stating $7^9 - 8$ i can't be divided by 2.  That $7^9 - 8$ can't be divided by 2 is exactly what you were expected to prove. In this case you have to prove $\sqrt[3]3$ is irrational by proving there is no rational number $r$ where $r^3 = 3$. (Hint: just echo the same proof that there is no rational $r$ where $r^2 = 2$. It's the same but one more step.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just start off my assuming $(u,v) = 1$ i.e the fraction is fully reduced. Then it follows that;
 $$u^3 = 3v^3 \Rightarrow 3 \mid u^3 \Rightarrow 3 \mid u \Rightarrow u = 3M$$

Therefore $(3M)^3 = 27M^3 = 3v^3$ and so $9 \mid v^3$ which implies $3 \mid v^3$ and so $(v,u) \not = 1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: $u^3=3v^3$, $u=3M$ therefore $(3M)^3=3v^3$ and not $(3M)^3=v^3$

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot just say that $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is irrational; that is just restating that which you are trying to prove.  Adding "it is well known" does not help.

What you need to do is assume $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is rational; then  $\sqrt[3]{3} = \frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q \in \Bbb{Z}^+$ adn there exists such a pair $p,q$ such that g.c.d$(p,q) = 1$.

Then
$$\frac{p^3}{q^3} = 3 \\
p^3 = 3q^3 \\
p^3 = 3k \implies \exists n: p = 3n \\
27n^3 = 3q^3 \\
 q^3 = 9 n^3 = 3 (3n^3) \implies q = 3m
$$
but then both $p$ and $q$ are multiples of $3$, which contradicts the condition that g.c.d$(p,q) = 1$.

So if $\sqrt[3]{3}$ is rational it cannot be expressed as a reduced fraction, therefore it is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track,
Let $$\frac{u}{v}=\sqrt[3]3$$ be a rational number,  where $v,u$ are **coprime**
and $v\neq 0$
$$\implies\frac{u^3}{v^3}=3$$
$$\implies u^3=3v^3$$
As $v$ and $u$ are coprime, their cubes must also be coprime. But this is a contradiction ($u^3=3v^3$) and hence the assumption that $\sqrt[3]3$ is rational was false.

Answer (score 0):

As an elementary approach, I personally prefer to prove that given any truly rational number
$$
\frac ab\notin\mathbb Z
$$
we get truly rational powers
$$
\left(\frac ab\right)^n\notin\mathbb Z
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Namely, if any prime $p$ divides $b$ but not $a$, the same goes for $b^n$ and $a^n$.

---

The reasons I like this approach are

1. simplicity
2. generality

One can infer from this that an $n$-th root of an integer is either an integer or irrational. So it follows immediately that $\sqrt 2, \sqrt[3]3,\sqrt[5]{17}$, and generally any $n$-th root of an integer that is not a perfect $n$-th power will be irrational.